# Loading A JSON Url and Posting to Website

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I have been trying different coding methods, currently p5js.org's and I cannot see to get the json code to post to my website using document.write, however it does print to console. Any ideas?

```
var bibleVerse;

function setup() {
  loadJSON('http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=votd&type=json', gotData, 'jsonp');
}

function gotData(data){
  println(data);
  bibleVerse = data;  
}    

document.write(bookname.chapter.verse.text);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Why are you trying to use `document.write`?  If you want to write info to the page, don't use `document.write`, use the DOM (`.innerHTML` and such).

Comment: And if you are trying to use `document.write`, why doesn't `document.write` appear anywhere in the code you've shared?

Comment: i am trying to post the verse of the day to my website.

Comment: document.write(bookname.chapter.verse.text);

Comment: For your reference: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  "Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem".  Please provide *relevant* code for your website so those who are trying to answer your question can reproduce the problem using your code.  Otherwise you may get answers that do not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that [p5js](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON) works.

Instead of using `document.write`, you should identify where you want to see the data on your webpage and insert the data into that element.  You can do that by using the element's `id`.

For example, you want to put the quote into this paragraph:

`<p id="quote">Alternate Text</p>`

Then replace your `document.write` with this:

`document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = data;`

All put together, you JS code might look like this:

```
function setup() {

  loadJSON('http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=votd&type=json', gotData,     'jsonp');
}
  function gotData(data){
  document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = data;
  // note: var bibleVerse is never used
}
```

The `Alternate Text` is there just in case the JS functions fail.

---

Side note if you are new to web development:  if you do not wish to use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function, you should put this JS script **inside** the the `<body>` at the bottom.  That way your page loads first, then the JS executes.

Comment: Be careful with `innerHTML`; if the text contains HTML content, it will not be escaped. It is safer to use text nodes for text content.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this code through sequentially:

```
var bibleVerse;

function setup() {
  loadJSON('http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=votd&type=json', gotData, 'jsonp');
}

function gotData(data){
  println(data);
  bibleVerse = data;  
}    

document.write(bookname.chapter.verse.text);
```

It does the following steps:

1. Declare a `bibleVerse` variable
2. Declare a `setup` function
3. Declare a `gotData` function
4. Write `bookname.chapter.verse.text` to the document.

This will not work, because:

1. Nothing is calling setup (unless you omitted this from your code)
2. `document.write` is running *before* `gotData` is run.
3. `bookname` is undefined.
4. Even if `document.write` was happening in the correct sequence, that is not really supported after a page has finished loading.

I'd recommend you:

1. Put a placeholder on the page that will hold the verse (like `<div id="verse"></div>`)
2. Attach your `setup` function to a DOM event (like `document.addEventListener('load', setup);`)
3. Remove `document.write`, and add something like this to your `gotData` function:

Sample:

```
var textNode = document.createTextNode(data.bookname.chapter.verse.text);
document.querySelector('#verse').appendChild(textNode);
```